# Can't instantiate view controller Swift

Tags: swift, navigation, viewcontroller

My code worked well so far. I do not see what I could change to make it bug like that. When I want to return the user to the home page, it works, but a few seconds after the previous ViewController reappears on the screen.

I've tried to change "as! HomeViewController" with "as UIViewController" or as NavigationViewController but it keeps going to the previous ViewController.

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let balanceViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! HomeViewController
    self.present(balanceViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Btw, you don't have to downcast instantiated controller to your custom subclass or `UIViewController` either if you just need to present it.

Answer (score 0):

> When I want to return the user to the home page...

You should use `UINavigationController.popToViewController(_:animated:)` to return to a `UIViewController`:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let balanceViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! HomeViewController
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(balanceViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: It doesn't work...  Plus, the problem is the same in AppDelegate with self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! UIViewController